# Rails vs Django Deployment

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby, django, deployment

I'm looking for at either Rails or Django for some opensource development..

I recently tried to install Gitorious (awesome rails app) on a server..

Gave up after about 4 days of crying at 3AM,

Which is generally the easiest to deploy?

Thanks

Daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know django, although have some experiences with python. I heard nice things about it, but I will mention rails related hosting/deployment options.

- [capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano) - if you want to deploy manually on your own server/VPS, this is a way to go. It might take some time, you have to learn and understand capistrano. There are several resources for this (i.e. [peepcode](http://peepcode.com/products/capistrano-2), [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/133-capistrano-tasks), ..)
- [heroku](http://heroku.com/) - are you familiar with [git](http://git-scm.com/)? If you are, heroku is a super elegant way to deploy your rails application by git. If you have a mini application, like a personal blog or a presentation, than you can use it for free!
- [google app engine](https://appengine.google.com/) - personally I did not use, even not try it so far. But some guys recommend it. You can run your rails application on JRuby.

Although it is not strictly rails related, if talking about deployment, [chef](http://www.opscode.com/chef) should be mentioned. Chef is written in ruby. It is tool for bootstrapping and managing servers on various providers. If you are beginning with rails, check out chef later.

I would recommend you to start with Heroku if you choose rails.

Comment: Thanks... Yeah i'm a git fanatic =P hmmmm so much to know so little time!

Comment: Me too.. heroku, chef cookbooks, open source code sharing, various deployment solutions built on git prove how great git is! it is simple idea with huge implications.

Answer (score 3):

For Django, Fabric ( http://docs.fabfile.org/0.9.3/ ) is a popular automation and deployment tool.

Answer (score 1):

[Capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/) and [Webistrano](https://github.com/peritor/webistrano) for rails do they job

Answer (score 1):

HELLO,

You can use passenger to deploy your rails application without pain :) Capistrano and webistrano are alternatives too

Answer (score 1):

You can also try [cherokee](http://www.cherokee-project.com/doc/cookbook_django.html).

Answer (score 0):

At the moment Rails has better tools for deployment. Of course you can use Capistrano and other tools mentioned in this thread with Python/Django as well, it just mean you have to learn some bits of Ruby notation.

Fabric is great and feels more natural if you are Python person however has much less out-of-the-box functionality.